# Operation on Matlab arrays

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indexing, operators

I'm quite new to Matlab and I was trying to figure out a line in a code I'm trying to review and understand.

```
data(:,U==0)=[];
```

To give some context :

1. The class of the variable *data* is a double, and inside of it I have an array (matrix) of numbers :

For exemple :
data = [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12; 13 14 15 16; 1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8; 9 10 11 12; 13 14 15 16]

2. U is a double too, given by the standard deviation of the data :

```
 U=std(data);
```

For the same exemple :
U = [4.7809    4.7809    4.7809    4.7809]

The question I am asking is about the first line of code I shared at the beginning, I think I understood a bit how arrays were working on Matlab, but I can't find any real documentation about what the *"U==0"* means here.

So what I'm really asking is how this line of code will affect my dataset if my variable "data" contains a lot more data in it?

If you have some piece of documentation to further understand the concepts behind this kind of operations on matrixes and arrays in Matlab I would be really grateful if you would share them with me.

Thank you so much in advance if you have some kind of solution or explanation.
Have a great day !

Comment: Search for logical indexing in MATLAB. That first line is deleting (assigning an empty array`[]`) to every column (`:` <- take whole row) that satisfies that `U==0`. As long as `size(data,2)` is the same as `length(U)`, then this will work, as MATLAB allows you to index "everything" in a axis (row/column/whatver) with the `:` operator

Comment: Note that your title is a complete red herring. Its irrelevant that the data is double, this will work in any matrix type

Comment: Ok thank you so much I got it, I pretty much understood anything except from the way the condition could be verified in an array like this. Thank you